# Trabajar con listas sin columnas conocidas

Tags: c#

Tengo un formulario que recibe una lista, para mostrar en pantalla y permitir elegir, o incluso, buscar en ella, algo simple para no usar controles pesados y caros como `DevExpress`, el tema es el siguiente:

El formulario recibe la lista, los nombres de columnas y el tamaño de columnas, todo marcha bien, pero ahora le he agregado una columna que se debe enviar y que es la suma de todos los campos previos, para que se pueda realizar una búsqueda sobre esa única columna y se puedan filtrar las filas que coinciden.

Esta columna la he llamado `ItemString` y el linq va asi:

```
private ICollection<dynamic> Listado;
```

...

```
var lista = (from i in this.listado
             where (i.ItemString.Contains(sValorBuscado))
             select i).ToList();
```

y me lanza el error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ItemString'
>   System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

A que se puede deber esto?, como se puede evitar esto dado que no se conocen los nombres de las columnas?, en la depuración veo que si llega la columna `ItemString`, pero parece no reconocerla el linq.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la definición de la variable `listado`?

Comment: Hola. gracias por tu interés en ayudarme. esta es la definición: private ICollection<dynamic> Listado;

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: por favor, para aclaraciones usa [edit] y agrega la informacion directamente en la pregunta

Comment: Podrías agregar de qué manera le asignas un valor a tu variable `listado`. ¿Le asignas con un tipo anónimo?

Comment: Yo no termino de entender tu pregunta. Te recomiendo que prepares un [mcve] para que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que utilizas un tipo `dynamic`, el cual finalmente al ser usado en Linq es un tipo anónimo, deberás declarar las variables con las que estás trabajando:

```
var lista = (from i in this.listado
             where (i.ItemString.Contains(sValorBuscado))
             select new {
                 ItemString = i.ItemString
                 //Aquí pones el resto de las propiedades
             }).ToList();
```

Con esto, estás diciendo explícitamente con qué columnas debe trabajar esa estructura. La verdad es que sería una genialidad que la estructura de datos anónimos detecte en automático los datos de tipo `dynamic`.

Comment: Hola Flxtr, gracias por la respuesta: El asunto es que ese formulario de búsqueda recibe la lista de otro, digamos el de clientes, entonces recibe un campo codigo, descripcion e ItemString, pero si lo recibe de un formulario "Documentos" recibirá "Fecha, Cliente, ItemString", entonces las columnas puede ser varias, de distntos nombres, excepto por "ItemString" las demas no son conocidas.

Comment: Desafortunadamente no se tiene esa flexibilidad, pero lo que puedes hacer es recibir un tipo genérico y con eso, sí puedes trabajar sin problemas de interpretación de tipos entre dynamic y anónimos